# How do I see my list of advancements in Mineclone 2?

Tags: mineclone-2

I'm playing [Mineclone 2](https://content.minetest.net/packages/Wuzzy/mineclone2/) which is a clone of Minecraft made using Minetest.  There should be some button to press to show me the list of advancements, only I can't figure out what to press.

Embarrassingly, I pressed this key combination by accident, but I can't seem to figure out what it is.  I didn't get the answer by Binging [`mineclone 2 show advancements`](https://cn.bing.com/search?q=mineclone+2+show+advancements) (I can't access Google right now).  I asked the AI chat bot [HuggingChat](https://huggingface.co/chat/), and it said "Ctrl + Shift + A", but this didn't work.

**Question**: How do I see my list of advancements in Mineclone 2?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  You press `i` to open your inventory, then click the gold goblet icon

> [image: Mineclone inventory with gold goblet icon highlighted using freehand squiggles]

This brings up the list of advancements:

> [image: screenshot of list of advancements]